# jet-application-mark in laravel 8.x

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8

I know that a vue component has an ending tag. But in laravel 8.x, I found `jet-application-mark` without an ending tag like this...

```
<div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center">
    <a href="/dashboard">
        <jet-application-mark class="block h-9 w-auto" />
    </a>
</div>
```

If you have laravel installed, you will find the full source code here...

```
resources > js > layouts > AppLayout.vue (line no: 11)
```

Is it a vue component? of anything else?

Comment: Vue components, just like HTML elements can use self-closing tags. See https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended

Answer (score 3):

It Jetstream from the new Livewire package that replaces Laravel Auth packages:

From the [webpage](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/introduction.html): Laravel Jetstream is a beautifully designed application scaffolding for Laravel. Jetstream provides the perfect starting point for your next Laravel application and includes login, registration, email verification, two-factor authentication, session management, API support via Laravel Sanctum, and optional team management.

If you need to change the icon you must publish the Jetstream views with this command:

```php
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
```

> Next, you should customize the SVGs located in the
> resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/application-logo.blade.php,
> resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/authentication-card-logo.blade.php,
> and
> resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/application-mark.blade.php
> components.

Source: [Jetstream Documentation](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/installation.html#application-logo)

If you want to learn what is Livewire you can read the docs in https://laravel-livewire.com

Comment: are you advertising this package or something?

Comment: No, im just trying to help what the user is asking...